# How can I call a MVC action method from jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
.on('click', '#logoutLink', function (e) {
   var $link = $(this);
   var href = $link.attr('data-href');
});
```

In an MVC action method I have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        WebSecurity.Logout();

        return RedirectToLocal("/");
    }
```

In jQuery I am familiar with $('#xx').load(href); but for this
I don't need to do anything with the return value. Is there a
way I can call this action method from the web page with jQuery
without it being a load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**jQuery ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you could just execute a post to the action method:

```
.on('click', '#logoutLink', function (e) {
    var $link = $(this);
    var href = $link.attr('data-href');

    .ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: href,
      data: data // if you have any or leave out
    }).done(function(){ // do something when it is done, or don't });
});
```

or use the shorthand version [**jQuery post**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) similar to this:

```
.on('click', '#logoutLink', function (e) {
    var $link = $(this);
    var href = $link.attr('data-href');

    $.post(href); // no callback required if you don't need to have it.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'd be better off with [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp), since it seems you want to redirect at the end of the function.

If you truly need to use Ajax, use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "LogOff"
}).done(function() { 
 window.location =
});
```